# .net framework button on click not firing and page reloads

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

Hello I'm having a problem with firing a function on click on a button :

```
<asp:Button  ID="Btn_Export1" runat="server" Text="Export Detail Ventes Brutes" CssClass="button" visible="true"/>
```

the code behind in the page.aspx.cs :

```
Btn_Export1.Click += new EventHandler(
                    (obj, sen) => BtnExport(obj, sen, Envlst[i - 1].IdEnveloppe));
```

when I click the button, the page gets reloaded and the method BtnExport is not fired.

P.S (UPDATE):
I forgot to mention that this button is added dynamically to a tabpanel of TabContainer of AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: Give OnClick="BtnExport" in aspx page

Comment: I want to use it this way in fact.

Comment: Where are you adding that event handler? You need to set it in every postback, on Load event.

Comment: @gonzalorf I'm adding it when a filter button is clicked.